# Asp.net if statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im having a problem with an IF statement.

The purpose of this statement is that all 3 managers must approve an order before it can prossesed.

This is the statement :

```
Dim RstAllchk
Dim RstAllchk_numRows
Set RstAllchk = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RstAllchk.ActiveConnection = MM_DBConn_STRING
RstAllchk.Source = "SELECT comitee.OrderNo, comitee.Bart, comitee.Carel, comitee.Charl             FROM comitee WHERE (((comitee.OrderNo)='" + Replace(RstAllData__varOrderNum, "'", "''") + "'));"
RstAllchk.CursorType = 0
RstAllchk.CursorLocation = 2
RstAllchk.LockType = 1
RstAllchk.Open()
RstAllchk_numRows = 0

    if  (RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Bart").Value)= "Approved" then
if  (RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Carel").Value)= "Approved" then
    if  (RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Charl").Value)= "Approved" then 

set cdata1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cdata1.ActiveConnection = MM_DBConn_STRING
cdata1.CommandText = " UPDATE TblOrderData SET Fldapproved = 'Approved'  WHERE FldOrderID  = '" & RstAllData__varOrderNum  & "'" 
cdata1.CommandType = 1
cdata1.CommandTimeout = 0
cdata1.Prepared = true
cdata1.Execute()
cdata1.ActiveConnection.Close

set cdata2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cdata2.ActiveConnection = MM_DBConn_STRING
cdata2.CommandText = " UPDATE TblOrderDetail SET FldMainapproved = 'Approved'  WHERE FldOrderNum  = '" & RstAllData__varOrderNum  & "'"
cdata2.CommandType = 1
cdata2.CommandTimeout = 0
cdata2.Prepared = true
cdata2.Execute()
cdata2.ActiveConnection.Close
```

`

Sometimes if only one of the managers confirmed the order, the order is still approved. I have been struggling with this for days. Hope any of you can give me some advice.

Thanks

Comment: dude hard coded values? and your SQL statements should be parametrized. That's some nice SQL injection risks there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming VB.NET:

```
IF (RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Bart").Value = "Approved" AND _
    RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Carel").Value = "Approved" AND _
    RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Charl").Value = "Approved") THEN
```

In C#:

```
if (RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Bart").Value == "Approved" &&
    RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Carel").Value == "Approved" &&
    RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Charl").Value == "Approved")
```

Comment: Your c# needs to be `==` not `=`

Comment: @Scott - You _could_ edit it yourself... If you see an obvious mistake - correct it. It's the Stack Overflow way.

Answer (score 0):

With C# (&& is And , == is equal)

```
if ( RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Bart").Value == "Approved"

 &&  RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Carel").Value == "Approved"

 && RstAllchk.Fields.Item("Charl").Value == "Approved"
)

{

   //treatment

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all like

```
(if var1 == x && var2 == y && var3 == z) {
    //Do what you want
}
```